# Can't access my website using IP/~account, showing not supported

Tags: laravel, cpanel

I can't access my temporary URL, it just shows "Not Supported". I uploaded laravel files. i've configured the index.php and .env[showing not supported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfj5X.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help center pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Specific pages that you should read include [How Do I Ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please take these introductory steps and then edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what web server you are using, Apache or Nginx, you can follow official document to configure your web server. [Web Server Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6#web-server-configuration)

To use laravel, you must configure your server properly. Just uploading code to server will not make your website work as expect. The must important part of configuration is directing all requests to the `index.php`.

And here is part of my config file of Nginx.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-website.test;
    root "/path/to/my-laravel-project/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;

    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Remember that website `root` should point to `./laravel-project/public` directory, because `laravel-project/public/index.php` file will handle all request for your website.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your web root is the syksxyz directory then the public path will be syksxyz/public
2. To make sure its working you can add an index.html file in the public folder to see whether the mapping is correct before debugging the php part of it.